# Tasks in task scheduler not triggered properly

Tags: windows, email, powershell, task, taskscheduler

I have certain tasks that run and send reports via e-mail daily in task scheduler. Suddenly, I stopped receiving e-mails and also getting the following error for few tasks.

Task Scheduler failed to start "\TaskA" task for user "system\abc". Additional Data: Error Value: 2147750687.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Probably your task as already running and hung. Make sure to set a proper timeout for the task to prevent this issue in the future.

The value `2147750687` can be converted to hexadecimal notation which will make it `0x8004131F`. Looking this error code up gives [`SCHED_E_ALREADY_RUNNING`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383604(v=vs.85).aspx#SCHED_E_ALREADY_RUNNING) with the description:

> An instance of this task is already running.